# Inaccessible host: `savingsplans.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `eu-west-1' region

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk

I am trying to List all available savings plan in my account using

```
var savingsPlans = new AWS.SavingsPlans();
const listResponse: AWS.SavingsPlans.DescribeSavingsPlansResponse = await savingsPlans.describeSavingsPlans({nextToken: token}).promise();
```

But getting following error. Please help.

```
 "error": {
        "message": "Inaccessible host: `savingsplans.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `eu-west-1' region.",
        "code": "UnknownEndpoint",
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "hostname": "savingsplans.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "retryable": true,
        "originalError": {
            "message": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND savingsplans.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
            "code": "NetworkingError",
            "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
            "hostname": "savingsplans.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "retryable": true,
            "time": "2022-03-03T05:32:05.683Z"
        },
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/billing.html#limits_billing), the endpoint url is:

> savingsplans.amazonaws.com

You can [manually specify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/specifying-endpoints.html) correct endpoint:

```
var savingsPlans = new AWS.SavingsPlans({endpoint: 'https://savingsplans.amazonaws.com'});
```

Comment: But I am not passing any region here.
```
var savingsPlans = new AWS.SavingsPlans();
const listResponse: AWS.SavingsPlans.DescribeSavingsPlansResponse = await savingsPlans.describeSavingsPlans({nextToken: token}).promise();
```

Comment: @SanyuktaAgrawal I don't know why it asks for the wrong url (maybe you have old sdk?), but you can manually specify correct one. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and Mark the answer useful if it works

Comment: @SanyuktaAgrawal No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: Hi Marcin, I am getting another issue when I added the solution you gave.
``` "error": {
        "message": "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'eu-central-1'. ",
        "code": "InvalidSignatureException",
        "time": "2022-03-03T09:01:44.704Z",
        "requestId": "xxxx",
        "statusCode": 403,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 34.70692160170614
    }
```

Comment: @SanyuktaAgrawal For the new issue, a new question should be asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349658/savingsplans-credential-should-be-scoped-to-a-valid-region