# SavingsPlans: Credential should be scoped to a valid region

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk, aws-cost-explorer

I am trying to List all available savings plan in my account using

```js
var savingsPlans = new AWS.SavingsPlans({endpoint: 'savingsplans.amazonaws.com', region: region});
const listResponse: AWS.SavingsPlans.DescribeSavingsPlansResponse = await savingsPlans.describeSavingsPlans().promise();
```

But getting following error in some scenarios. In some scenarios, it is working fine. What could be the issue? Please help.

```
"error": {
        "message": "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-2'. ",
        "code": "InvalidSignatureException",
        "time": "2022-03-04T09:47:56.535Z",
        "statusCode": 403,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 97.23145392059766
    }
```

I am running above code for all regions in my account. Fore some regions, I am not getting any error. But for some regions I am getting error. For example: I am getting error for region `ap-northeast-1` but I am not getting error for `us-east-1` region.

When I run the same code with Go SDK, it is working for both regions. not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you try: `new AWS.SavingsPlans({endpoint: 'https://savingsplans.amazonaws.com', region: 'us-east-1'})`?

Comment: @SanyuktaAgrawal Could you please update the question with the updated code and output?

Comment: What is `region` set to? Can you please post the full code? And is this running locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved when we use v3 aws-sdk version.

```
import { SavingsplansClient, DescribeSavingsPlansCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-savingsplans";
 const savingsPlans = new SavingsplansClient();
 const command = new DescribeSavingsPlansCommand(})
 const listResponse = await savingsPlans.send(command);
```

Seems there are some issues in v2 for savings plans.